# Whats wrong with the function params and the comparison condition?

Tags: bash, function, operators

im figuring out how to get this working..
Im not very experienced with Bin Bash,
but I have this script:

The variables.cfg contains:

pvp="0400 1200 2000"

```
#!/bin/sh

CONFIG_FILE="/home/nacion/variables.cfg"
source $CONFIG_FILE

#Arreglar tiempo
ATM (){
  if [ $((1+2)) -gt 24 ];
    then
      $a=$1 + $2
      $b=$a-2400
      echo $b
  fi
}

declare -a VcHorarios=($pvp)

for HoraAR in "${VcHorarios[@]}" 
do
```

I dont know why is not passing the param

```
  ES=$(ATM $HoraAR 500)
  HorarioSv="&b&lMX $((HoraAR-300)) - AR $HoraAR H - ES $ES H"
done

echo $HorarioSv
```

The result:

```
[root@anda ~]# /home/nacion/vcprueba.sh 
&b&lMX 1700 - AR 2000 H - ES H
[root@ns500347 ~]#
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: 3 is never greater to 24.

Comment: @choroba it is if theyre strings...

Comment: @123: `-gt` uses numeric comparison.

Comment: `$a=$1 + $2` and `$b=$a-2400` are not legal shell syntax/commands.

Comment: Add `set -x` to the top of the script and see what is actually being run.

Comment: @123 This question doesn't involve string comparisons, and you're being unhelpfully pedantic by bringing them up.

Comment: @chepner The question doesn't even involve a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the `$` from *variable* names inside `$((...))`. `$1` and `$2` are not variables; they are positional parameters.

```
if [ $(($1 + $2)) -gt 24 ];
```

Once you manage to enter the body of the `if` statement, the correct commands are

```
a=$(( $1 + $2 ))
b=$(( a - 2400 ))  # or $(( $a - 2400 )), if you prefer
```